# why admin url showing as blank in magento 2?

Tags: magento2

i installed the magento 2 at local server and when i try to open my admin page to login following this url:
`https://localhost/magento/admin` then my admin login page showing as blank page like this please see that image :
[image]

can someone help me if anyone have solution?,

Answer (score 0):

Go to your magento 2 installation directory through terminal and run these commands.

If you are on local machine then run this chmod command, else see the magento doc for the correct files and folder permissions.

```
chmod -R 777 ./*

php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush

rm -rf generated/*

php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```